# What package must I load to be able to write \mathbb{Z}?

Tags: packages, amsmath

Downloaded TeXworks a couple weeks ago and have been using it to type my mathematics homework in LaTeX. I keep having to write sentences such as: `Let $n$ be an integer.` There are times when I would much prefer to write similar statements in symbols. For example: `Let $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.` But every time I click to compile I get a message saying `\mathbb{Z}` is not recognized. I am assuming this is because I am not loading the proper package.

I am writing `\usepackage{amsmath}` before I begin the document. Should I be loading a different or additional package to be able to use these additional symbols, such as the symbol for the integers? If so, what package?

Comment: Add `\usepackage{amssymb}` to your preamble. This is also covered in the [Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) (Table 213, p 68).

Comment: Thank you. I tried it out real quick, and I have it working now.

Comment: Thanks for the PDF, as well. Seems like it will answer many future questions.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit.

Comment: @Corentin thank you. I took the time to read your link about marking inline code. Wasn't aware that was the convention. I'm a noob. Appreciate the tip.